# How do I change a namespace reference based on an input string?

Tags: c#

I have multiple versions of a library that I want to be selected by the user. Each of these libraries contains the same classes and methods. How do I use a user selected string change the namespace a class or method references. For example:

```
using LibVersion1;
using LibVersion2;

namespace MyProgram
{
    public void DoAThing()
    {
        string version = "";
        if (user selects 1)
        {
            version = "LibVersion1";
        }
        else
        {
            version = "LibVersion2";
        }
        {version}.SomeClass myClass = new {version}.SomeClass();
        myClass.runThing();
    }
}
```

I assume I have to do some sort of Type.GetType(), but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Comment: This seems like an x/y problem. There is limited usage for this in versioning. However, this seems very uncommon and overly baked and will result in unnecessary complications to let a user choose a namespace, unless you have a compelling use case... I would first rethink your problem to reassure yourself there is no other ways to solve this business logic issue

Comment: The referenced namespaces are to run different versions of an external software. I can't change the external software, and different versions still need to be accessed. My solution up to this point is to have a different version of my program for each version of the external software. Being able to choose the version would simplify this.

Comment: You can also use a switch-case statement.

Comment: Ahh ok, well there is a new feature in core / net5 `System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext` which you might get some mileage out of, however, you could also likely get a certain amount of functionalities with factories, contracts and switch statements, either way I don't envy you having this problem